# Obtain value from <span> attributes inside <td>

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My vb.net program is generating a checkboxlist with several checkboxes.  While building the checkboxes, I'm also setting a couple of Attributes.  When the user clicks the box, I'm trying to access the values of the attributes in javascript.

The vb.net looks like this:

```
L = New ListItem
thisROLEn = "A"
L.Value = dr("apr_key")
L.Text = Trim(dr("apr_name"))
L.Attributes("Role" & thisROLEn) = Trim(dr("ROLE_DESC"))
L.Attributes("Title") = AppToolTip
AppList.Items.Add(L)
```

Here's what a TR section of the generated html looks like:

```
<tr>
<td>
    <span RoleA="User" RoleB="Admin" Title="Approve access">
        <input id="MainContent_AppList_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$AppList$0" value="7" />
        <label for="MainContent_AppList_0">Finance</label>
    </span>
</td>
```

I can get the value of the checkbox just fine.  My question is how do I access the value of "RoleA" from javascript?

Comment: How are you getting the value of the checkbox?

Comment: looping through the list, then with this:  var CB = document.getElementById("MainContent_AppList_0").checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea based off your comment.

```
var checkbox= document.getElementById("MainContent_AppList_0");
var span = checkbox.parentNode;
var isChecked = checkbox.checked;
var roleA = span.RoleA;
```

Comment: that got me real close ... I can now see it by span.getAttribute("RoleA") ... span.RoleA is "undefined" ... but thanks!! This was kicking my butt all afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the attribute value by `getAttribute`

```
document.getElementById('MainContent_AppList_0').parentNode.getAttribute("roleA")
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you are able to access check box, based on that I have created a sample pseudo code here:

```
var a=document.getElementsById('ctl00$MainContent$AppList$0');
var b = a.parentNode;
var roleA = b.getAttribute('RoleA');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you are mentioning about the attribute name and its casing then I would suggest you to check it again. As for the Id its not even mentioned the code so I simply used the same as mentioned in the name, and under normal circumstances both name and id are same when rendered.